# Importing txt with line breaks

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to import '.txt' file to python dataframe. However, whenever my 'text' or 'description' column includes a new line or line break, it recognizes as a new row.

For example, my txt file includes and it recognizes as 5 lines, but actually it is one data point (one row). How can I import it correctly as I intend to?

```
status_id,text,date,lang,date_joined,source,truncated_text,description
929519008734314496,40 Acres and a Mule by Brazilian Princess #NowPlaying,2017-11-12 01:19:35,en,2013-05-09 09:36:56,Twitter Web Client,False,"The Official Twitter of Brazilian Princess
I make Christian Trap Music 
Creator of @AlphababyStore
I am a trafficking and domestic violence
Survivor
Acts 2:38"
```

My target would be

```
status_id,text,date,lang,date_joined,source,truncated_text,description
929519008734314496,40 Acres and a Mule by Brazilian Princess #NowPlaying,2017-11-12 01:19:35,en,2013-05-09 09:36:56,Twitter Web Client,False,"The Official Twitter of Brazilian Princess I make Christian Trap Music Creator of @AlphababyStore I am a trafficking and domestic violence Survivor Acts 2:38"
```

Comment: A CSV file where a field spans multiple rows is supposed to have quotes around the field.

Comment: OP, please include what you've tried so far so we aren't simply doing it for you.

Comment: The file DOES have an opening quote.  I don't see the closing one.

Comment: If I add the closing quote to that last line, `pandas.read_csv` imports it exactly as you want.

Comment: Thank you, Tim Roberts. Problem Solved.